# Differential form with this integral on these curves

Tags: calculus, differential-forms, curves

In $\mathbb{R}^2$ consider $\gamma_0$ as the circumference centered in $(0, 0)$ with radius 1 and $\gamma_1$ as the circumference centered in $(1, 1)$ with radius 4. I'm looking for a differential form $\omega$ defined in $\mathbb{R}^2-\{(0, 0), (1, 1)\}$ such that:

$$\int_{\gamma_0}{\omega}=1 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \int_{\gamma_1}{\omega}=-1$$

I also want that form to be $\mathscr{C}^1$ where it's defined.

I only understood that the form cannot be exact but I don't how to continue, please keep the example as simple as possible.

Comment: I assume you mean "circle", not "circumference"? In English, "circumference" is the name for the length around a shape, not the name of a shape.

Comment: Hint: Consider the complex function $$f(z) = \frac Az + \frac B{z -(1+i)}$$ for the appropriate values of $A$ and $B$.